# Spring data update query with @Query

Tags: jquery, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have a problem with this query:

```
@Modifying  
@Query("UPDATE NotificationHasUser u SET u.read=true WHERE u.pk.user = ?1")
void setNotificationsAsRead(User user);
```

I would like to update all false `read` value (because I have to switch the unread notifications to read) for a specific username.
I have even tried with 1 instead of true but I always receive this exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read=1 where id_username='luca'' at line 1
```

This is the database schema:
[image: schema]

Do you have an idea of the problem?

Comment: Enable query log and see the issued query

Comment: Could you post the User entity?

Comment: I found the error, read is maybe a keyword for MySql so if I call the field isRead all work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, read is a keyword for MySql so if I call the field isRead all work fine. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) the list of keywords